# Why doesn't OnCompleted run on Visual Studio but runs on LINQPad?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand how async is implemented internally. As I understand OnCompleted() is not blocking. these two lines are executed "correctly" on linqpad.
However, on Visual Studio I don't see: "This will be done after"
even with `Task.Delay(5000).Wait()`

```
Task.Delay(5000)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .OnCompleted(() => Console.WriteLine("This will be done after"));

Console.WriteLine("This will be done first");
```

Comment: When you say "However, on Visual Studio I don't see", what does Visual Studio refer to? A console application?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the console write line and see if it hits. Some c# apps, if they’re not console apps, don’t direct that stream to the output. Setting a breakpoint will show you if the code executes. Or use “Debug.writeline(“”);” instead. It outputs to the output window of vs

Comment: when console write the "This will be done first", does the console waiting another writing to it or show "press any key to continue"?

Comment: Yes it is  a console App .

Comment: Task t = Task.Delay(20000);
            t.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("I can see this   after 20 sec");
            t.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => Console.WriteLine("I can not see this"));

Answer (score 1):

In console application you need to make the console wait for another reading so you have to use `Console.ReadLine()` in the end of the code to wait another read like this :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Task.Delay(5000).GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() => Console.WriteLine("This will be done after"));

            Console.WriteLine("This will be done first");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```